# Помещение в автозагрузку программы на C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Имеется консольная программа на C++. Что в её коде дополнительно нужно прописать, дабы она автоматически при запуске попала в автозагрузку Windows?

Comment: #include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
void PL(std::string Name,std::string URL)
{
 HKEY hKey; 
 


 RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
      "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
      NULL, 
      "", 
      REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, 
      KEY_SET_VALUE, 
      NULL, 
      &hKey,
      NULL);

 if (hKey) 
 { 
  RegSetValueEx(hKey, Name.c_str() , NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)URL.c_str(), strlen(URL.c_str())); 
  RegCloseKey(hKey); 
 }
}

int main()
{
 PL("Windows system host drivers","C:\\Windows\\System32\\DevicePairing.exe");
}

Answer (score 0):

Ловите [работающий пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935564/save-me-simple-add-to-startup-via-registry/15937683#15937683) регистрации программы в автозагрузке windows, используя реестр.

Comment: Просто поместите ярлык программы в автозагрузку